# How can I add an object that is added with Ext.create to my Viewport?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm new using Ext JS and I need to add a button in my Viewport.

I have tried adding it as an item but it doesn't work when I click on it:

```
items: [ {        
  xtype: 'datepicker',
  width: 211

},
{        
  xtype: 'datepicker',
  width: 211                            
},
{
  xtype: 'button',
  text: 'Search',
  width: 211
 },                     
],
```

So then, in the official [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html) I have found another way to add it:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text     : 'Button',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            // this == the button, as we are in the local scope
            this.setText('I was clicked!');
        },
        mouseover: function() {
            // set a new config which says we moused over, if not already set
            if (!this.mousedOver) {
                this.mousedOver = true;
                alert('You moused over a button!\n\nI wont do this again.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But I want it in the west region I defined in my Viewport and I have no idea about how to achieve this since I'm completely new at Ext JS.

My code:

```
function init() {
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',

        launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                storeId:'prices',
                fields:['name', 'priceNight', 'totalPrice', 'Check-in', 'Check-out'],
                data:{'items':[

                ]},
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'
                    }
                }
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    title: 'West',
                    region: 'west',
                    margins: '0 5 0 5',
                    flex: .3,
                    collapsible: true,
                    split: true,
                    titleCollapse: true,
                    items: [
                        {        
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            width: 211

                        },
                        {        
                            xtype: 'datepicker',
                            width: 211                          
                        },
                        {
                            //I want the button here.
                        },                      
                    ],              
                }, {
                    title: 'Center',
                    region: 'center',
                    collapsible: false,
                    items: {
                        // I want to add it just there  
                        xtype: 'grid',
                        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('prices'),
                        columns: [

                        ],
                    }
                }]
            });
        }

    });
}
```

I would like the button here:

[image: a busy cat]

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured out how to do it! I'm going to post here what I did so maybe it will result helpful for some people:

It's just simple as invocating it using a variable.

Button code:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text     : 'Button',
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            // this == the button, as we are in the local scope
            this.setText('I was clicked!');
        },
        mouseover: function() {
            // set a new config which says we moused over, if not already set
            if (!this.mousedOver) {
                this.mousedOver = true;
                alert('You moused over a button!\n\nI wont do this again.');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In your viewport you just have to add it as an item:

```
...
items: [
  {
    items: button //button is the variable that we defined when we created the button
  }
]
...
```

Final result:

[image]

I hope this will help someone who is having the same question as me :)